# Django static file not loading. Bad error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, backend

[image: Image of error]

I tried loading style.css in static file but it wouldn't work. I made sure to configure STATIC files in settings.py like this

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static'))]
```

All my paths are correct and I loaded static. I cleared my cookies and the CSS still wouldn't work.

Comment: Did you set this to `DEBUG = False`?

Comment: Did you add your templates folder in your Templates DIR?

Comment: Yes I did. I did the same thing os.base_Dir as style.css

Comment: Could you show all the code of your settings.py?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/j2Y8pVVH here is settings.py

Comment: Is this a bug? Nobody could answer me

Answer (score 0):

if you are running this on django's built-in server then one thing you can do is to make sure your static files folder is in the same directory as the manage.py file because when we run the server as `python manage.py runserver` the relative path for everything else starts from the directory where `manage.py` is

Comment: It's in the same directory